# How to pass Django request object in user_passes_test decorator callable function

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I am using Django user_passes_test decorator to check the User Permission.

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: has_add_permission(u, "project"))
def create_project(request):
......
```

I am calling a callback function has_add_permission which takes two arguments User and a String. I would like to pass the request object along with it is that possible? Also, can anyone please tell me how are we able to access the User object inside the decorator directly.

Comment: I'm curious, how did you end up going about this? Did you write your own decorator?

Comment: Instead of using decorators, I am checking for permissions inside the view code itself. It gave me a better control over the view logic.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you cannot pass request to `user_passes_test`. To understand why and how it works, just head over to the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.1/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py):

```
def user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request.user):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse.urlparse(login_url or
                                                        settings.LOGIN_URL)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse.urlparse(path)[:2]
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path()
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(path, login_url, redirect_field_name)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

This is the code behind the `user_passes_test` decorator. As you can see, the test function passed to the decorator (in your case, `lambda u: has_add_permission(u, "project")`) is passed just one argument, `request.user`. Now, it's of course possible to write your own decorator (even copying this code directly and just modifying it) to also pass the `request` itself, but you can't do it with the default `user_passes_test` implementation.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I guess either I have to write a new decorator or do it inside the view code.

Answer (score 12):

Note that Django 1.9 introduced [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin), which uses a method `test_func` as test function. This means the request is available in `self.request`. So you can do something like that:

```
class MyView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    def test_func(self):
        return has_add_permission(self.request.user, self.request)
```

This only works with class-based views however.

Answer (score 6):

I found editing `user_passes_test` to have the decorated function operate on `request` rather than `request.user` not to be overly difficult.  I have a short version in [this blog post](http://blog.jdotjdot.com/2014/06/decorator-decorator/) about a view decorator decorator, but for posterity, here's my full edited code:

```
def request_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the request passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the request object and returns True if the request passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            # urlparse chokes on lazy objects in Python 3, force to str
            resolved_login_url = force_str(
                resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL))
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse(resolved_login_url)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse(path)[:2]
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                    (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path()
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(
                path, resolved_login_url, redirect_field_name)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

Pretty much the only thing I did was change `if test_func(request.user):` to `if test_func(request):`.