# Show error message when decorator fails

Tags: django, python-decorators

The decorator is working fine but I would like to display an error message (I'd like to use *messages framework*) if the user doesn't belong to any of the required groups. Here's the decorator:

```
def group_required(*group_names):
    """Requires user membership in at least one of the groups passed in."""
    def in_groups(user):
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if bool(user.groups.filter(name__in=group_names)) or user.is_superuser:
                return True
        return False
    return user_passes_test(in_groups)
```

I call it using something like:

```
@require_http_methods(['GET'])    
@group_required('supervisor')
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

I tried using this [snippet](https://github.com/jedie/django-tools/blob/master/django_tools/middlewares/ThreadLocal.py) to use *messages framework* (since this requires the *request* object) but it realized that *messages framework* middleware didn't appear installed inside the decorator.

I'm willing to change whatever it takes :)

Update:

What I'm looking for:

```
def group_required(request, *group_names):
    """Requires user membership in at least one of the groups passed in."""
    def in_groups(user):
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user.groups.filter(name__in=group_names).exists() or user.is_superuser:
                return True
            else:
                # I'm getting:
                # You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Group is not allowed')
        return False
    return user_passes_test(in_groups, request)
```

Comment: I just logged what request contains and it's not the request object. I think my problems is passing the request object to the decorator

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need threadlocals in this use case. And normally when threadlocals seems to be the only way to go in a Django app, there could be some mis-structured context layers. Comparing w/ the threadlocals, I would rather to duplicate `user_passes_test` and then modify it to pass `request` to `in_groups` (We could not pass `request` to `is_group` easily without modifying the code of `user_passes_test`. Check the question: [How to pass Django request object in user_passes_test decorator callable function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872560/how-to-pass-django-request-object-in-user-passes-test-decorator-callable-functio).) (Maybe a ticket for this?)

Furthermore, `bool(user.groups.filter(name__in=group_names))` would caused items to be retrieved to DB adapter and Python instance before deciding the existence, using `exists()` and thus `user.groups.filter(name__in=group_names).exists()` to directly return bool result from DB backend is far more efficient here.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I changed the query statement and looks better. Regarding the message issue, I did the replacement but I'm still getting the "You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware", which I have but I guess this is out of its context, any idea how to make messages framework available in this point?

Comment: @chachan Did you override the user_passes_test ? How did you fix the part of getting the request object inside group_required ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Sorry, I can't tell at the moment, that was 4 years ago