# How to test user ownership of object using Django decorators

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm working on a Django project and trying to figure out how I can test for user ownership and allow editing or redirect based on the result.

I have a model `Scene`. `Scene` is linked to `User` to track which user created a particular `Scene`:

```
class Scene(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    [rest of Scene model]
```

I have a URL pattern to edit a particular `Scene` object like this:

```
url(r'^scenes/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/', SceneUpdateView.as_view(), name='scene-edit'),
```

I have a logged in user via django-allauth. I want only `Scene` owners to be able to edit `Scenes`.

I'm trying to figure out how to use a decorator to test if `scene.user.id == self.request.user.id` for the particular scene called by the URL.

Do I need to send URL information into `permission_required` or `user_passes_test` decorators (is this possible)?

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872560/how-to-pass-django-request-object-in-user-passes-test-decorator-callable-functio, and if this isn't a duplicate, this at least should give some hints on how to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a custom decorator for your specefic need.
Note: I'm using function based view, you will have to modify the code to class based view if you want:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from yourmodels.models import Scene

#Custom decorator
def must_be_yours(func):
    def check_and_call(request, *args, **kwargs):
        #user = request.user
        #print user.id
        pk = kwargs["pk"]
        scene = Scene.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if not (scene.user.id == request.user.id): 
            return HttpResponse("It is not yours ! You are not permitted !",
                        content_type="application/json", status=403)
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return check_and_call

#View Function
@must_be_yours
@csrf_protect
def update_scene(request, pk=None):
    print pk
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        #modify merely
        pass
```

Urls:

```
url(r'^scenes/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/', 'update_scene'),
```

Comment: Is there  any way of generalizing this across multiple model class??

Answer (score 0):

In Function Based Views it's common to see decorators. Yet, in Class Based Views (CBV) it's more common to use `Mixins` or [`QuerySet`](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/checking-ownership-through-the-userpassestestmixin.html).

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18176411/7109869), one can create the following custom `Mixin` that overrides the dispatch method

```
class UserOwnerMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.object.user != self.request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return super(UserOwnerMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is a generalized way across multiple model class, as long as one is using `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`.

Then use it in the CBV in a similar fashion to

```
class MyCustomView(UserOwnerMixin, View):
```